# How to make android project compatible in Tizen platform?

Tags: android, wear-os, samsung-galaxy-gear

I have developed android wear application in Android Studio. I want to publish my application in Samsung Galaxy app store. But, I found out that Samsung uses different OS - Tizen altogether. As Samsung doesn't use Android SDK, Is there any way to make Android project compatible with Tizen SDK like making changes in a Manifest file or adding some library etc?

Any help or pointers are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a specific app store issue and not a programming question as defined in the [help] guideline. For issues related to an app store, contact that store's support department via the contact links on their site.

Comment: My question was was more of how to make it compatible with Samsung SDK if we create android wear app in Android Studio by adding some commands in Manifest file or something. I guess that comes under programming question only.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to make it more clear what you're asking, then.

Comment: And regarding programming question only allowed, there are many questions on Stack OverFlow which are not programming questions. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080423/how-much-does-it-cost-to-publish-android-apps nobody voted it till now. I am not complaining anything about anyone here. Just giving you an example.

Comment: I have updated my question. Hope this works.

Comment: That question you linked should have been closed. It's also off-topic. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. Existence of a previous question is irrelevant. The [help] has the most current guidelines for this site.

Answer (score 3):

1. Samsung wearable devices have its own OS: Tizen. This OS is completly different with Android OS.
2. When you create an APK for mobile device you can put wearable's APK inside it. So that when the APK isinstalled in handheld the wearable APK file will be installed into your paired wearable device.
3. Google Play now can help to publish wearable APK file only on wearable mobile device. Only for Android Wear 2.0 OS. Such devices have its own Google Play.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vyacheslav. I have developed my wear app in Android Studio. Is there any way where we can modify any file in a project or add some commands in manifest file or import any library so that it supports Tizen SDK as well?

Comment: Tizen is a totally different OS. Like Windows is not Linux

Comment: It even has got its own IDE https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download

Comment: So, I will have to rewrite entire code in Tizen Studio in order to have my application in Samsung Galaxy Store?

Comment: Also do you know how many OS does wear device has apart from Android, iOS & Tizen?

Comment: most of devices are have those OS.